# Peso Symbol in C#

Tags: c#

```
if (num1 == 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nThe " + num2 + " kilo/s of {0} " + 28 + " per kilo ", "GRAPES");
    Console.WriteLine("The total amount is {0}{1}", num2.ToString("en-PHI"),num2*28);
}
num2.ToString("en-PHI")
```

I try this one but it doesn't work at all .. it just copy the en-PHI..

Comment: What is the expected result of output?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to provide the *culture* `en-PHI`... although that isn't a valid culture name apparently. Perhaps you just want `phi` as the language?

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("phi");
var text = string.Format(culture, "The total amount is {0:c}", num2 * 28);
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

The `c` format specifier is "currency".

That's the way of printing the currency symbol known for a specific culture... now that might not do exactly what you want, but it's probably a matter of finding the right culture.

If you really just want to hard-code the [peso character (U+20B1)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b1/index.htm) you can do that directly:

```
 Console.WriteLine("The total amount is \u20b1{0}", num2);
```

Now if that prints a "?" it means the current console encoding or font doesn't support the peso symbol. Running this from the command line will set it to UTF-8:

```
> chcp 65001
```

Make sure the font you're using supports the character as well.

Comment: Mr. Jon can you give me an example program that show this symbol "₱" Thank you for your respond..

Comment: @Shanks: I have - the second snippet, once you've got the right settings. But to get that from a culture, you'd need to find a culture name that uses that as the default currency. I don't know that off-hand, which is why I've given you the hard-coded option as well.

Comment: Yeah your right.. I finally find out that this symbol "₱" is not allowed in c# language..

Comment: @Shanks: What do you mean by "is not allowed in C# language"? How were you trying to use it where the rules of C# itself are relevant? It's not a valid *identifier* as far as I'm aware, but I can't see how that would be a problem.

Comment: As an aside, you can also set the encoding in the Console with `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;`

Comment: I added another question how can I run a c# program in notepad++.. Its so annoying.. I can't find the answer..